# Translation of "She has a nice look"

Tags: translation

*“Sie hat eine schöne Sicht”* or *“Sie hat einen schönen Anblick”* or something else?
*Look* in the meaning of the manner of view, or the motion of eyes when viewing.

Comment: Eine schöne Bewegung der Augen beim Schauen? Was soll denn das sein? Das soll ein englischer Ausdruck sein?

Comment: "She has a nice look" in English to me means like "She went and looked around thoroughly"

Answer (score 5):

> Sie sieht gut aus

would be the most intuitive that comes to mind, as in *"She's good looking"*.

*"Sie hat eine schöne Sicht"* means *"She has a nice view"*, implying her looking at something or out of a window, etc. As in she has a great view out of her window, for example.

If you mean she's good at seeing things quickly or making out details: *"Sie hat einen guten Blick"*. I can't really translate this back to English, but a rather cumbersome translation would be: "She has a good glimpse".

Answer (score 4):

> "look in the meaning of the **manner of view**, or the **motion of eyes** when viewing."

To express this we may say the following:

> Sie hat einen schönen Blick.

But this is an unidiomatic literal translation. Some better variants are:

> Sie schaut (so) schön.
>   Ihre Art zu schauen ist schön.

Mostly however we'd hear people say this:

> Sie hat schöne Augen. *(She has got beautiful eyes)*

Answer (score 3):

`Sie hat eine schöne Sicht` is a valid sentence, but means she has a good view. You may use it, if you tell about a holiday of her and she had a good view from her hotel.

`"Sie hat einen schöner Anblick` is wrong. Correct would be `Sie ist ein schöner Anblick`. It's meaning “She has a nice look”, but I wouldn't use it. It is a positive message, but I expect a catch is you say it.

As a compliment you can use `Sie sieht schön/gut aus`. Or just `Sie ist schön`.
As a big compliment you may also use `Sie sieht super/toll/fantastisch aus` or `Sie ist wunderschön`.

Answer (score 0):

> She has a nice look. = The look of her is nice. = She has dressed up
>   nicely. = She looks nice today.
>
> Sie schaut hübsch aus. = Sie ist hübsch anzusehen. = Sie sieht hübsch
>   aus.

In German you would not say her look is nice. It's not her and her look in German. They are not separate. Either she is nice looking or she is not. If you want to talk about her hairdo, makeup or dress you'd need to specifically mention this:

> Sie ist heute hübsch angezogen. Ihr Outfit sieht gut aus. Ihr Outfit
>   sieht nett aus. Sie hat sich heute herausgeputzt. Sie ist adrett gekleidet.

Or a close one would be:

> Sie sieht adrett aus.
>   http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/adrett

This would probably be the closest match to "she has a nice look". Because you cannot look "**adrett**" without having clothes on or having combed your hair.

The only drawback to **adrett** is that it's no longer commonly in use.

http://www.globalglossary.org/en/de/de/adrett

Suggests for example: gepflegt and smart as alternatives. Which again means she has groomed herself and is not "just" pretty.

http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/adrett
Maybe even proper. But then proper is no longer pretty or nice look. More like well dressed or appropriately dressed.